# Como guardar variavel e usar depois do refresh da pagina

Tags: php

```
//variavel recebe de input html
$ssid = @$_POST['user']; 
 if(isset($_POST['enviar'])
{
  //deveria printar valor na tela
  echo $ssid;
}
```

A variavel `$ssid` recebe um valor do input, mas quando clico no botao enviar o valor da variavel some junto com o refresh da pagina 
como salvo o valor da variavel para usar depois do refresh da pagina?

Comment: tentou guardar ela em $_SESSION?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O php é **stateless**, logo cada requisição é independente, não relacionada a anterior, pois o estado do atributo não é mantido. Sendo assim voce pode guardar na sessão da seguinte forma:

```
<?php 
// session_start inicia a sessão
session_start();
//variavel recebe de input html
$ssid = @$_POST['user']; 
$_SESSION['ssid'] = $ssid;
```

Comment: Não funcionou nem mesmo com session
quando entra no if(isset), o valor some

Comment: Funcionou, mas tive que trocar o metodo de $_POST para $_GET

Comment: Show, se você teve que trocar de POST para GET é porque seu formulário esta mandando como GET, só sugeri POST pois como você colocou isso no seu exemplo deu atender que seu form era POST.  Só não entendei porque minha resposta não foi marcada como a correta sendo que respondi bem antes.

Answer (score 0):

Para conseguir armazenar a variável mesmo após a atualização da página, usa-se o $_SESSION.

Para iniciar a sessão no arquivo você está trabalhando = `session_start();`

```
$_SESSION['ssid'] = @$_POST['user']; // Aqui você está armazenando a sua varivel recebida na $_SESSION; 

 if(isset($_POST['enviar'])
{
  echo $_SESSION['ssid']; 

}
```

Caso você queira remover a session, utiliza-se unset($_SESSION['ssid']);

Para saber mais sobre sessions, no site do PHP tem o manual dela https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: mesmo assim não funcionou

Comment: Funcionou, mas tive que trocar o metodo de $_POST para $_GET